# Lakshmi and Parvati teasing each other's spouse - is this folklore or scripture?

Tags: shiva, vishnu, lakshmi, parvati

The Srivaishnavite preacher Velukkudi Krishnan quotes the original Sanskrit and also explains in Tamil:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PIr8TBNKj04

Is this scripture or folklore?

Very rare instance of Siva-Vishnu rivalry in good humor.

> Lakshmi: Where is that beggar?

> Parvati: How would I know – you have to ask Vamana who went to beg from Bali

> Lakshmi: Where is the Dance-performance today?

> Parvati: You have to ask the one dancing at Brindavana

> Lakshmi: Where is the fawn (carried by Siva) ?

> Parvati: Where is the pig (Varaha)

> Lakshmi: Where is the old bull (Nandi)?

> Parvati: Only the cowherd (Krishna) would know

The Sanskrit transribed as best as I can:

> L: Bhiksharthi satkvayatah

> P: Sutanubalimakhe

> L: Tandavam kvadya bhadre

> P: Manye Brindavanante

> L: Kvanusa mrigashishuhu

> P: Naiva jane varaham

> L: Bale kaschinna drishtah jaratha vrishpatihi

> P: Gopayevasya vetta

> L: Leela sallapayittham jalanidhi himavatkanyayoh trayatam nah

looks to be of very recent (> 18th cent) origin from the South.

Comment: Most of your recent questions are sort of repetitive trying to seek similar stuff - real or mythology, this is what I get the feeling, accept it or deny it! It seems you are on some sort of mission here!

Comment: Our scripture is a continuum - high concepts, usually in high-flown Sanskrit.  But there are lots of"folk" themes - like Draupadi washing her hair in Dusshasana;s blood (upcoming question :-)).  The dividing line between high scripture to folk scripture interests me. @just_do_it .

Comment: Well quite a few of them are analogies/metaphors and are to be understood by the person on spiritual path. Literal meaning are for non-seekers :)

Comment: As long as you are seeking, you won't get anywhere.  Seeking, even to be one with God, is an impediment.  I am deeply concerned about recent dilutions,distortions and packaging and merchandising of Hinduism - and I am unable to maintain advaitic detachment from these goings on @just_do_it .

Comment: I don't know why but it looks kinda nice and cute. Two Goddess are teasing each other.

Comment: 'quotes the original Sanskrit' - maybe you should transcribe the original Sanskrit in the post then it makes it easy to look for the source.

Comment: done @sv. as best as I could.